# Trait which returns an iterator

Tags: rust

## Setup

---

Say I have the following trait `Stack` which simply defines a `pop` and `push` operation:

```rust
trait Stack<T> {
    fn push(&mut self, data: T);
    fn pop(&mut self) -> Option<T>;
}
```

I can test any given implementation of my trait with:

```
fn test(stack: &mut dyn Stack<i32>) {
    stack.push(1);
    stack.push(2);
    stack.push(3);

    assert_eq!(stack.pop(), Some(3));
    assert_eq!(stack.pop(), Some(2));
    assert_eq!(stack.pop(), Some(1));
    assert_eq!(stack.pop(), None);
}
```

For example, here's an implementation that uses a vector underneath the hood:

```rust
struct StackWithVec<T> {
    vec: Vec<T>,
}

impl<T> Stack<T> for StackWithVec<T> {
    fn push(&mut self, data: T) {
        self.vec.push(data);
    }

    fn pop(&mut self) -> Option<T> {
        self.vec.pop()
    }
}
```

Which we can test using our `test` function:

```rust
fn main() {
    test(&mut StackWithVec {
        vec: Vec::<i32>::new(),
    })
}
```

This works and all is good.

## Adding `into_iter`

---

Now let's say I want to add a new function to my trait `into_iter` that consumes `self` and returns an `Iterator<Item = T>`:

```rust
trait Stack<T> {
    fn push(&mut self, data: T);
    fn pop(&mut self) -> Option<T>;
    fn into_iter(self) -> dyn Iterator<Item = T>;
}
```

I attempted to implement the above function for our `StackWithVec` implementation as such:

```rust
struct StackWithVecIntoIter<T>(StackWithVec<T>);

impl<T> Iterator for StackWithVecIntoIter<T> {
    type Item = T;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        self.0.pop()
    }
}

impl<T> Stack<T> for StackWithVec<T> {
    fn push(&mut self, data: T) {
        self.vec.push(data);
    }

    fn pop(&mut self) -> Option<T> {
        self.vec.pop()
    }

    fn into_iter(self) -> StackWithVecIntoIter<T> {
        StackWithVecIntoIter(self)
    }
}
```

However the compiler complains:

```
error[E0053]: method `into_iter` has an incompatible type for trait
  --> src/main.rs:30:27
   |
30 |     fn into_iter(self) -> StackWithVecIntoIter<T> {
   |                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   |                           |
   |                           expected trait object `dyn Iterator`, found struct `StackWithVecIntoIter`
   |                           help: change the output type to match the trait: `(dyn Iterator<Item = T> + 'static)`
   |
note: type in trait
  --> src/main.rs:4:27
   |
4  |     fn into_iter(self) -> dyn Iterator<Item = T>;
   |                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   = note: expected fn pointer `fn(StackWithVec<_>) -> (dyn Iterator<Item = T> + 'static)`
              found fn pointer `fn(StackWithVec<_>) -> StackWithVecIntoIter<T>`
```

What's the correct way to implement such a behavior (either by modifying the trait or by modifying my implementation)?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73980141/implement-trait-that-has-function-which-return-traits
is very similar to your problem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Now let's say I want to add a new function to my trait `into_iter` that consumes self and returns an `Iterator<Item = T>`:
>
> ```rust
> trait Stack<T> {
>     fn push(&mut self, data: T);
>     fn pop(&mut self) -> Option<T>;
>     fn into_iter(self) -> dyn Iterator<Item = T>;
> }
> ```

This is one application of associated types. Add an associated type to your trait that's returned by `into_iter`:

```rust
trait Stack<T> {
    type IntoIter: Iterator<Item = T>;

    fn push(&mut self, data: T);
    fn pop(&mut self) -> Option<T>;
    fn into_iter(self) -> Self::IntoIter;
}
```

and then to implement it you just set that associated type as well:

```rust
impl<T> Stack<T> for StackWithVec<T> {
    type IntoIter = StackWithVecIntoIter<T>;

    fn push(&mut self, data: T) {
        self.vec.push(data);
    }

    fn pop(&mut self) -> Option<T> {
        self.vec.pop()
    }

    fn into_iter(self) -> Self::IntoIter {
        StackWithVecIntoIter(self)
    }
}
```

Note that this is essentially how the [`IntoIterator` trait works](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/iter/trait.IntoIterator.html).

If it's actually `IntoIterator` you're working with, you may just want to make `Stack` a [subtrait](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch19-03-advanced-traits.html#using-supertraits-to-require-one-traits-functionality-within-another-trait) of `IntoIterator`:

```rust
trait Stack<T>: IntoIterator<Item = T> {
    fn push(&mut self, data: T);
    fn pop(&mut self) -> Option<T>;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, this is super helpful. Using the supertrait, how would you define the function signature for the test function? The following type annotation did not work for me `Stack<i32, IntoIter = dyn Iterator<Item = i32>>`.

Comment: Just `&dyn Stack<i32>` should work. Because `Stack<T>: IntoIterator<Item = T>` implies the second part of what you have there already.

Comment: The compiler doesn't like that, it wants to specify a concrete type for `IntoIter`: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=1830de71b7a89be649e163f70b513644

`specify the associated type: \`Stack<i32, IntoIter = Type>\``

Comment: Oh right, Rust requires specifying the associated type for trait objects. You'll either have to accept that (which would you can use `Stack` generically, but not dynamically) or remove the associated type and return `Box<dyn Iterator<T>>` from `into_iter()`