# Trait in function signature with a non-concrete generic argument

Tags: rust

I have the following trait:

```rust
trait Stack<T>: IntoIterator<Item = T> {
    fn push(&mut self, data: T);
    fn pop(&mut self) -> Option<T>;
}
```

I can test some implementation of my stack with:

```rust
fn test() {
    let mut stack: StackLinkedList<i32> = StackLinkedList::new();

    stack.push(1);
    stack.push(2);
    stack.push(3);

    assert_eq!(stack.pop(), Some(3));
    assert_eq!(stack.pop(), Some(2));
    assert_eq!(stack.pop(), Some(1));
    assert_eq!(stack.pop(), None);

    for i in 1..=10 {
        stack.push(i);
    }

    for (i, x) in stack.into_iter().enumerate() {
        assert_eq!(x, 10 - i as i32);
    }
}
```

However, let's say I wanted to generalize the function `test` such that it can accept any arbitrary `Stack<i32>` implementation. At first I tried the following:

```rust
fn test(&mut stack: dyn Stack<i32>)
```

However the compiler complains:

```
error[E0191]: the value of the associated type `IntoIter` (from trait `IntoIterator`) must be specified
  --> src/main.rs:70:25
   |
70 | fn test(&mut stack: dyn Stack<i32>) {
   |                         ^^^^^^^^^^ help: specify the associated type: `Stack<i32, IntoIter = Type>`
```

I thought that because we defined the subtrait `:IntoIterator<Item = T>` that the associated type `IntoIter` would be inferred (aka it must be `Iterator<Item = T>`). Hm okay, that's fine, let's just explicitly define it:

```rust
fn test(&mut stack: dyn Stack<i32, IntoIter = dyn Iterator<Item = i32>>)
```

This indeed did not fix the error and instead gave me back 3 compiler errors. I tried fiddling around (adding `Box`, using `mut` instead of `&mut`), but I can't seem to figure out what the correct way to write the function signature to allow for the desired behavior.

[Playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=5fe9e33480083a91bce509ffe7d585b1)

Note: This question is a follow up on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76150403/11070463) (see comments).

Comment: You linked to the playground, not to a specific playground

Comment: @PitaJ fixed the playground link

Comment: [`Box<dyn Iterator>`](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=bf5617957ceecb2b1586bf52226f3269) can work for the function definition, but that requires that `IntoIter` for each implementor actually **be** `Box<dyn Iterator>`, which is not the case for, say, `Vec`.

Comment: As  I mentioned on the other question, you'll have to make your own [`fn into_iter(self:  Box<Self>) -> Box<dyn Iterator<Item = T>>`](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=d468fe8c703feb31602edfc24e2f32da) for this to work dynamically.